# How do I combine two columns from two different tables into one column

Tags: google-bigquery, union, union-all

I have two tables containing sales data for Apple and Samsung

Table for Apple Sales

```
cust_id | apple_products 
0001      iPad
0002      iPhone
0002      Apple Watch
0003      Macbook
0003      Apple Watch
```

Table for Samsung Sales

```
cust_id | samsung_products 
0001      Galaxy S10
0002      Galaxy Tab 1
0004      Galaxy Tab 2
0004      Galaxy Note
```

I wonder how should I write my query to combine these two tables

Table for Total Sales

```
cust_id | products 
0001      Galaxy S10
0001      iPad
0002      Galaxy Tab 1
0002      iPhone
0002      Apple Watch
0003      Macbook
0003      Apple Watch
0004      Galaxy Tab 2
0004      Galaxy Note
```

I am thinking of using `UNION ALL` but I am not sure if it's the best way. Here is the query that I am using.

```
select 
  cust_id
  , apple_products as products
from apple_sales
UNION ALL
  cust_id
  , samsung_products
from samsung_sales
```

Comment: Why are they in two separate tables anyway rather than one table with a vendor and a product column? If the structure has to be separated then UNION (ALL if duplicates are possible and desired) seems perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Unioning is fine.  To really embrace BigQuery, consider:

```
with unioned as (
  select cust_id, 'Apple' as brand, apple_products as product from apple_sales
  union all
  select cust_id, 'Samsung' as brand, samsung_products as product from samsung_sales
)
select
  cust_id,
  array_agg(struct(brand,product)) as devices
from unioned
group by 1
```